# Even numbers n such that n divides $1^n + 2^n... (n-1)^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Even numbers n such that n divides $1^n + 2^n ... (n-1)^n$
I am aware of that odd numbers n divide this, but I want to find all solutions for this.
The only insight I came up with is that n cannot be of the form 4n+2.

Comment: Are you trying to write $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^n$?

Comment: edited already, sorry

Comment: Why is the statement always true for odd $n$?

Comment: You should do more research before posting, at least trying some even numbers and reporting any pattern.  Also the sum of consecutive squares has a well-known closed form, so one can approach your problem that way.

Comment: I already said an insight that the number is not of the form 4n+2, which was the 1st case of the solved recursive function. Maybe you should stop gatekeeping posts here in stack exchange because its very hard to find information in internet if you dont know what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written, for odd $n$,

$n|1^n+2^n+...+(n-1)^n$

Let's assume $n$ is even, $n=2k$.

$i^n \equiv (n-i)^n \pmod{n}$

First observation is that if $n/2$ is odd, the sum will be odd too. Thus, the sum won't be divisible by $n$.

Second observation, let's assume $n$ is divisible by 4, and $n$ divides the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^n$:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^n\equiv 2\cdot(\sum_{i=1}^{n/2-1}i^n) + (\dfrac{n}{2})^n\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$

The above congruence implies that $n/2$ should divide the half of the sum. Explicitly,

$\sum_{i=1}^{n/2-1}(i^n) + (\dfrac{n}{2})^n\cdot{\dfrac{1}{2}}\equiv 0 \pmod{n/2}$

Because that $(\dfrac{n}{2})^n$ is even when $n/2$ is even, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n/2-1}(i^n)$ should be even too. This means that $n/4$ should also be even.

We recursively get a similar result until for some $k$, $(n/2^k)$ is odd. This is the final stage of the recursion, and at that stage, the final sum will be odd.

Comment: sorry, i dont follow how it would contradict the statement.

Comment: can you elaborate on the last part

Comment: If $n/2^k$ is odd, you'll see that the sum $1^n + ... + (n/2^{k-1} -1)^n$ is odd, which means it won't be divisible by $n/2^{k-1}$ And the other terms left will all be even, so the total expression will be odd too.